# how to programming save a node with tags

Tags: taxonomy-terms, services

I want to use drupal as my webservices, so I develop a module to implement `hook_services_resources`.

I use postman (chrome's extension) to post data to drupal.

```
var data={"uid":"1","title":"xxx","type":"bookmark","field_tags":{"und":[{"tid","4"},{"tid","5"}]}};
```

implement in services

```
function _bookmark_helper_resource_create($data){
  $entity_type="node";
  $entity=entity_create($entity_type,$data);
  if(!entity_save($entity_type,$data)){
    services_error("Error saving entity."406);
  }
  return $entity->id;
}
```

There is 3 questions:

1.it seems that node created successed,I can see the node in drupal,but I receive 406 error.

2.There is two tag in the node,but once I click one tag(path taxonomy/term/5), I can't see the node I just add.

3.How can I add new tag to node?

Can someone help me out? Thanks very much!!